# AWS Lambda: Basic Python Rest API to add 2 numbers and return their sum

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-requests, aws-api-gateway

I'm trying to understand, how to create a REST API using AWS Lambda and Python. For this, I'm creating a simple Lambda function that will accept 2 numbers from the user and return the sum of these numbers.

Code of my Lambda function:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    # TODO implement
    try:
        #User Input:n1 & n2
        _query = event['queryStringParameters']
        _n1 = int(_query['n1'])
        print(_n1)
        _n2 = int(_query['n2'])
        print(_n2)
        del(_query)
    
        #Response Body
        _body = {
            'n1': _n1,
            'n2': _n2,
            'sum': _n1+_n2
        }
        
        print(_body)
    
        #Response Header
        _header = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
        
        print(_header)
    
        #Response
        _response = {
            'statusCode': 200,
            'headers': json.dumps(_header),
            'body': json.dumps(_body)
        }
        
        print(_response)
        
        return _response
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

This Lambda function is connected to AWS API Gateway to allow public access. I have not configured any authentication mechanism for API Gateway.

I'm trying to call this API from another python program.

Source code of calling program:

```
from requests import get

try:
    _url = 'URL_of_the_lambda_function'
    _params = {
        'n1':1,
        'n2':2
    }

    r = get(
        url=_url,
        params=_params
    )

    data = r.json()


    print(data)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This program is getting executed on the terminal with the help of VS Code. When I'm trying to run the program, I'm getting

```
{'message': 'Internal server error'}
```

Can anyone please help me to understand, what is the mistake with my code?

[N.B.: As suggested fellow community members:

1. I have converted `header` to dictionary.
2. I have added `try/catch` block to both(lambda and calling function)
3. I have tried to print every `header`, `response` and `body` objects
   ]

Comment: Would suggest adding a `try/catch` statement that would print out the error's message and stack trace so you could identify what's going on.

Comment: How did you set up API Gateway method? Is it proxy integration for Lambda, or not? Also, I'd suggest you to look at the CloudWatch, to see if Lambda function is executed and what does it show in the logs. If that doesn't help, I'd suggest you to execute the test from API Gateway (it can show possible errors) or turning on logs for API Gateway execution

Comment: The `headers` in your Lambda response should be a dict, not a JSON string. More generally, to debug this code, add additional print statements e.g. for the event (before trying to get the query parameters), and check CloudWatch Logs after triggering the Lambda function.

Comment: Furthermore, if you use the URL of the Lambda (`URL_of_the_lambda_function`) you are not going to call the API Gateway. You need to use the URL of your API Gateways stage that you can find in the API Gateway console.

Comment: Hi @Jens, I completely agree with what you are saying, and in the actual code, I'm using the actual URL of the lambda function, but since, I cannot post the URL in a public forum, I'm replacing it with 'URL_of_the_lambda_function'

Comment: Hi @Caldazar, I'm not using any proxy for API gateway, apart from 'Use Lambda Proxy Integration. Also, I have tested the cloud watch logs, and figured out the python code is returning the sum as expected, but I'm not able to understand, why I'm the calling function is giving an error

Comment: @Yash I know that you can't post the actual URL. My point is that `URL of API Gateway != URL of Lambda`. You have to use the former, not the latter.

Comment: @Jens, I'm tried to modify the URL of the code to the URL of API Gateway. Still, I'm getting the same error